# How to compare complex collections in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Let us say I have two table types (tables of object types) that I want to compare for equality...

The object types have multiple fields, say, an `integer`, `varchar2`, and `date`.

I have seen examples where people use `MULTISET EXCEPT` in order to effectively do a `MINUS` on two tables of `INTEGER`.

But this does not work with two tables of complex object types.

Also I have seen mentioned the use of `MAP MEMBER FUNCTION` in order to make complex collections work when using the `SET` operator, but no mention of `MULTISET` functionality.

The current way I am comparing for equality is to take table type 1 (TT1) and table type 2 (TT2) and say they are equal if `TT1 MINUS TT2 = 0 AND TT2 MINUS TT1 = 0`. But here I am just selecting the PK from both tables for the MINUS, I would also like to be able to compare more than one field.

I am hoping `MULTISET` is faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `MAP MEMBER FUNCTION` to support comparing nested tables of types.

```
--#1: Create object
create or replace type type1 is object
(
    a integer,
    b varchar2(100),
    c date,
    map member function compare return raw
);
/

--#2: Create map function for comparisons.
--Returns the concatenated RAW of all attributes.
--Note that this will consider NULLs to be equal!
create or replace type body type1 as
    map member function compare return raw is
    begin
        return
            utl_raw.cast_to_raw(to_char(a))||
            utl_raw.cast_to_raw(b)||
            utl_raw.cast_to_raw(to_char(c, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

    end;
end;
/

--#3: Create nested table of the types
create or replace type type1_nt is table of type1;
/

--#4: Compare.
--You could use MULTISET, but it's easier to use regular operators like "<>" "and =".
declare
    tt1 type1_nt := type1_nt(type1(0, 'A', date '2000-01-01'),
                             type1(0, 'A', date '2000-01-01'));
    tt2 type1_nt := type1_nt(type1(0, 'B', date '2000-01-01'),
                             type1(0, 'B', date '2000-01-01'));
    tt3 type1_nt := type1_nt(type1(0, 'B', date '2000-01-01'),
                             type1(0, 'B', date '2000-01-01'));
begin
    if tt1 <> tt2 and tt2 = tt3 then
        dbms_output.put_line('Pass');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Fail');
    end if;
end;
/
```

I don't know if this would be faster than manually comparing each attribute.  But I would guess the difference won't be significant.